# Change value of characters in string JAVA

Tags: java

I'm writing an android program that "Codes" your string. If you input "abz" it should output "bca" basically each individual character in that string is changed to the next one. I implemented this in JavaScript

```
 var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza",
 var newstr = '';

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (alphabet.indexOf(str[i]) != -1) {
        newstr += alphabet[alphabet.indexOf(str[i]) + 1];
    } else {
        newstr += str[i];
    }  
}
```

How would I do this in JAVA

Comment: Did you try doing it in Java?

Comment: I'd like to mention that a cipher like this is quite poor for encoding data securely.

Comment: Sorry, this type of questions is discouraged in StackOverflow. Admittedly you did *something* before (by implementing it in JS), but this is not enough... Show us some Java attempts we can fix!

Comment: Quite poor? Bit of an understatement, I'd say. I have faith in OP that they don't intend to use this for any serious security purposes.

Comment: Tag [tag:android] should be removed. Question is not about anything Android-specific.

Comment: There is no effort demonstrated by OP in trying to figure out the solution.

Comment: @ADTC I agree. Removed it.

Answer (score 2):

A few minor modifications:

```
String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza";
String newstr = "";

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (alphabet.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) != -1) {
        newstr += alphabet.charAt(alphabet.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) + 1);
    } else {
        newstr += str.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

Java does not have the `var` keyword like JavaScript so you'll have to explicitly type your variables. Another thing that's different is that `String`s are indexed using `string.charAt(pos)` rather than `string[pos]`.

Note that `String`s are immutable in Java so every time you append to a `String`, you're actually creating a new one, which causes considerable performance issues. A [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) or [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) would be better suited for this.

Live demo here: http://ideone.com/ZrZL0L

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the StringBuilder class.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(somechar);
sb.append(somechar);
sb.append(somechar);
```

like so. As pcnThird pointed out, the String class is immutable. The StringBuilder isn't, so it's great for this.

When you're done, get your string by `sb.toString();`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why people are suggesting using `charAt`, but I think you should iterate over the characters themselves

```
String s = /* words */;
char[] sentence = s.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    if (Character.toLowerCase(char[i]) == 'z') {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(char[i])) {
            char[i] = 'A';
        } else {
            char[i] = 'a';
        }
    } else {
        char[i]++;
    }
}
String encoded = new String(sentence);
```

This only creates a since additional string instance (no need for stringbuilder), and is relatively simple.